# How can I display a calendar control (date picker) in Oracle forms 9/10?

Tags: oracleforms

How can I display a calendar control (date picker) in Oracle forms 9/10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most forms projects I've worked already have a date picker, implemented as a separate form - e.g. I think one gets generated by HeadStart. I think it's also been implemented using a separate canvas in the standard forms template.

However, this question also asked on ittoolbox and answered here:

[Creating date picker calendar control in Oracle Forms](http://oracle.ittoolbox.com/groups/technical-functional/oracle-forms-l/creating-date-picker-calender-control-in-oracle-form-2187294)

Comment: As of 6/22/2011 the Oracle link is a 404 error. No replacement pages found.

Comment: darn you www.oracle.com and your webunfriendliness!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a Java Swing solution for Calendar.  This site is great for all things Java and how to implement in Oracle Forms.

http://forms.pjc.bean.over-blog.com/article-14848846.html

We at PITSS use this site often when dealing with our Hundreds of Customers.  http://pitss.com